# How can I add an array or a new value to the query condition?

Tags: database

I need to add a new type of content in my query condition, but I don't know how to do it.

This is the code I am using.

```
$query_result = $query->getQuery()
  ->condition('type','series'+ ......others items)
  ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

$query_result = $query->getQuery()
$query->condition('type', ['type1', 'type2'], 'IN')
      ->execute();